# JPA / Hibernate "simple" OneToMany Unidirictional / Clear of set does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but apparently I am not able to create a simple OneToMany relationship with hibernate.

Here are my tables how they look in DB:
[image]
I will only show relevant part, so the question does not get to bloated.
My User Looks like

```
@Entity(name = "CORE_USER")
public class User extends AbstractPersistentObject {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CORE_USER_TO_ROLE", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<UserRole>();      

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private Set<UserRoleParam> userRoleParams = new HashSet<UserRoleParam>();

    ...(getter and setters)

}
```

Here Core user role param entity

```
@Entity(name = "CORE_USER_ROLE_PARAM")
public class UserRoleParam extends AbstractPersistentObject {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private UserRole userRole;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_PARAMETER")
    private String paramter;

    ...(getter and setter)....
}
```

UserRole entity

```
@Entity(name="CORE_USER_ROLE")
public class UserRole  extends AbstractPersistentObject {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", length = 30, nullable=false, unique=true)
    private UserRoleEnum roleName;

    ...(getter and setters)
}
```

When I do this in my test:

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
public void saveUserRoleParametersTest() throws Exception {

    // load an user which exists and check params is zero
    UserDTO userDTO = userService.getUserDTO(Users.DE678_ACTIVE_ALLROLES.getObject().getId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO.getUserRoleParams());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, userDTO.getUserRoleParams().size());

    Map<UserRoleEnum, List<String>> userRoleParams = new HashMap<>();
    userRoleParams.put(UserRoleEnum.BASIC, new ArrayList<>());
    userRoleParams.get(UserRoleEnum.BASIC).add("BASIC_PARAM");

    // save params to user
    userService.saveUserRoleParameters(Users.DE678_ACTIVE_ALLROLES.getObject().getId(), userRoleParams);


    userDTO = userService.getUserDTO(Users.DE678_ACTIVE_ALLROLES.getObject().getId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO.getUserRoleParams());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, userDTO.getUserRoleParams().size());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, userDTO.getUserRoleParams().get(UserRoleEnum.BASIC).size());
    Assert.assertTrue(userDTO.getUserRoleParams().get(UserRoleEnum.BASIC).contains("BASIC_PARAM"));

    // delete params of user
    userService.saveUserRoleParameters(Users.DE678_ACTIVE_ALLROLES.getObject().getId(), null);

    userDTO = userService.getUserDTO(Users.DE678_ACTIVE_ALLROLES.getObject().getId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userDTO.getUserRoleParams());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, userDTO.getUserRoleParams().size());
}
```

here is also the user service method which I invoke:

```
@Override
public void saveUserRoleParameters(final String userId, final Map<UserRoleEnum, List<String>> userRoleParams) throws UserNotFoundException {
    User user = userDAO.get(userId);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(userId);
    }

    if (userRoleParams == null || userRoleParams.isEmpty()) {
        user.getUserRoleParams().clear();
    } else {
        List<UserRole> roles = userDAO.getUserRolesByEnums(userRoleParams.keySet());
        Map<UserRoleEnum, UserRole> enumToEntity = new HashMap<>();
        roles.stream().forEach(r -> enumToEntity.put(r.getRoleName(), r));

        for (Entry<UserRoleEnum, List<String>> entry : userRoleParams.entrySet()) {
            UserRoleParam urp = new UserRoleParam(enumToEntity.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(";")));
            user.getUserRoleParams().add(urp);
        }
    }
    userDAO.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

The problem is that my test fails on first service method call of `saveUserRoleParameters` which is (**EDIT:** now with sql log enabled):

```
DEBUG [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.264  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger@logStatement: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.version as version2_0_0_, user0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE1_38_0_, user0_.APP_LANG as APP_LANG2_38_0_, user0_.DEFAULT_MODULE as DEFAULT_3_38_0_, user0_.ORGA_UNIT as ORGA_UNI4_38_0_, user0_.USER_FULL_NAME as USER_FUL5_38_0_, user0_.USER_NAME as USER_NAM6_38_0_ from CORE_USER user0_ where user0_.id=?
DEBUG [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.270  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger@logStatement: select userrole0_.id as id1_0_, userrole0_.version as version2_0_, userrole0_.ROLE_NAME as ROLE_NAM1_41_ from CORE_USER_ROLE userrole0_ where userrole0_.ROLE_NAME in (?)
DEBUG [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.287  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger@logStatement: select userrolepa0_.USER_ID as USER_ID3_0_0_, userrolepa0_.id as id1_42_0_, userrolepa0_.id as id1_0_1_, userrolepa0_.version as version2_0_1_, userrolepa0_.ROLE_PARAMETER as ROLE_PAR1_42_1_, userrolepa0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID2_42_1_ from CORE_USER_ROLE_ROLE_PARAM userrolepa0_ where userrolepa0_.USER_ID=?
DEBUG [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.290  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger@logStatement: insert into CORE_USER_ROLE_PARAM (version, ROLE_PARAMETER, ROLE_ID, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN  [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.291  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper@logExceptions: SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
ERROR [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.291  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper@logExceptions: NULL nicht zulässig für Feld "USER_ID"
NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into CORE_USER_ROLE_ROLE_PARAM (version, ROLE_PARAMETER, ROLE_ID, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-175]
WARN  [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.291  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper@logExceptions: SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
ERROR [main] 12.05.17 08:46:50.292  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper@logExceptions: NULL nicht zulässig für Feld "USER_ID"
NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
```

Shouldn't jpa put the UserId where it belongs? What I want is a Unidirectional relationship where User knows about UserRoleParams but not the other way around. Like in the example here http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/relationship

**EDIT#2:**
I found a solution. I added following on User Entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
private Set<UserRoleParam> userRoleParams = new HashSet<UserRoleParam>();
```

Now I have the issue that clearing the set will not be persisted. My test fails as the second check if the `Set` is empty fails. It shows that the Parameters are still set.

Comment: Save the user before you save the CORE_USER_ROLE_PARAM

Comment: You haven't put `mappedBy="user"` on the `User.userRoleParams` field, since that is a BIDIRECTIONAL relation

Comment: @Stimpson: The user which I load is already existent as you can see in the beginning of the test where I load the user to check if the parameters are empty.

Comment: Then you save the user with id = null. Do you have autoincrement turned on or are you using a sequence for the id?

Comment: @StimpsonCat the user exists. I do not want to save to user with a new id. As the test shows. I get the user with an id and want to update the retrieved user.

Comment: Please enable debugging and show some sql statements

Answer (score 2):

The fields `User.userRoleParams` and `UserRoleParam.user` are part of a bidirectional relation. To do that you must add 
`mappedBy="user"` to the `@OneToMany` side.

You cannot have those two parts as independent relations (i.e unidirectional 1-N and unidirectional N-1) reusing the same FK column (*"USER_ID"*).

As for [your documentation you linked to in the comments](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany), the only use of unidirectional 1-N has **no field** on the other side (and you **do** have a field on the other side of the relation).

**User has changed their question since this answer!** Why do I bother?

Comment: you are right... in that case... that was when I was playing around and I accidentally posted the wrong code. What I want is a UNIDIRECTIONAL relation on the JPA Mapping side

Comment: It has its own column in the table CORE_USER_ROLE_PARAM which is USER_ID. I would appreciate if you either cold have more patience or stop yelling (write with capitalized letters)

Comment: You cant help, if the questions are changeing ;)

Comment: you are right... I made a mistake by copying a wrong code into the question. And I do not want to open a new question if I solved the old problem